# Error: The method createQueue(String) is undefined for the type Session

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

When I'm trying the code below, getting the following errors for Producer and & Destination. Am I using the right connection factory?

- The method createQueue(String) is undefined for the type Session

  ```
  import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
  import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
  import javax.jms.Connection;
  import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
  import javax.jms.Destination;
  import javax.jms.ExceptionListener;
  import javax.jms.JMSException;
  import javax.jms.Message;
  import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
  import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
  import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
  import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
  import javax.jms.Session;
  import javax.jms.TextMessage;  

      public class MQProdCons {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {            
          QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(getSendHost());              
          QueueConnection connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();  
          connection.start();
          // Create a session
          Session session = connection.createQueueSession(false,
                  Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
          // Connect to queues
          Destination requestQ = session.createQueue (getReportQueue());

          MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(requestQ);
          Destination responseQ = session.createQueue(getReceiveQueue());

          MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(responseQ);
          producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
  ```

Comment: That error implies you have a classpath issue at play

Comment: Could you include the full exception? Do you have the problem at build time or run time? How are you compiling and running the code? The code itself looks OK to me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
You have used wrong import. Use org.hibernate.Session and error will dissapear.